# How to have a similar enum like below, but to have it configured dynamically rather than static?

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I use the below static values enum as `repeatInterval` for `UILocalNotification`. Can this be made dynamic?

```
// RepeatInterval
enum RepeatInterval : String, CustomStringConvertible {
    case Never = "Never"
    case EveryMinute = "Every Minute"
    case EveryHour = "Every Hour"
    case EveryDay = "Every Day"
    case EveryWeek = "Every Week"
    case EveryMonth = "Every Month"
    case EveryYear = "Every Year"

    var description : String { return rawValue }

    static let allValues = [Never, EveryMinute, EveryHour, EveryDay, EveryWeek, EveryMonth, EveryYear]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `made dynamic`?

Comment: @user28434. I want it to be configured based on the user preferences. To remove if deemed unnecessary, and to add again, if possible.

Comment: do you want to add cases dynamically?

Comment: @iGenio, Yes...

Comment: @Shyam, you should think about using `Set<String>` then or something like that.

Comment: @user28434. Honestly, I don't understand, how this works. Trying to pick up pieces as I enter this land of iOS dev. :-/

Comment: @Shyam, can you provide more info about use-case?

Comment: for setting up localnotifications, I use this to set the repeatInterval. So, I can trigger the notifications to repeat based on the user's choice. But, say, if a user doesn't want the `EveryMinute` and `EveryYear` option to be shown, is it possible to not have them?

Comment: Enums must be compiled, you can not create them dynamically.

Comment: @SachinAmrale, Oh, Thanks.. Guess, I have to visit the drawing board, again...

Answer (score 0):

You can create the enum with all possible options what you have done and create a function which filters the allValues array based on user selection

```
// RepeatInterval
enum RepeatInterval : String, CustomStringConvertible {
    case Never = "Never"
    case EveryMinute = "Every Minute"
    case EveryHour = "Every Hour"
    case EveryDay = "Every Day"
    case EveryWeek = "Every Week"
    case EveryMonth = "Every Month"
    case EveryYear = "Every Year"

    var description : String { return rawValue }

    static let allValues = [Never, EveryMinute, EveryHour, EveryDay, EveryWeek, EveryMonth, EveryYear]
}

//filterArray function to remove unwanted enum values
func filterArray(interval: [RepeatInterval]) -> [RepeatInterval] {
    let filteredArray = RepeatInterval.allValues.filter { !interval.contains($0)}
    return filteredArray
}

//Usage
let r = filterArray([.Never, .EveryMinute, .EveryDay])

//prints [Every Hour, Every Week, Every Month, Every Year]
```

Comment: Thank you. On a separate note, will it be possible to add any new cases?

Comment: Adding separate cased is not possible, you may have to think of alternative solution..please upvote the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks for the suggestion. Although, it does make sense, it isn't applicable in my case. Thanks again @suhit..